# Is there a shutdown hook for a ProcessEnginePlugin in Camunda?

Tags: camunda

I'm implementing a plugin for the process engine of Camunda.

This is a simplified example:

```
public class FooPlugin implements ProcessEnginePlugin {
    public void preInit(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl processEngineConfiguration) {
       // Create a connection that needs to be closed
       Connection connection = //...
       // Where to put this code: `connection.close()`?
    }
    public void postInit(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl processEngineConfiguration) {
    }
    public void postProcessEngineBuild(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
    }
}
```

Is there a hook that I can use that is triggered when camunda (or the application server) is shutting down?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a ProcessApplication, you have the addition ònPOstDeploy`and`onPreUndeploy` hooks. The latter one should do what you need.
When using camunda spring boot, you can just listen on the event via

```
@EventListener
public void on(PreUndeployEvent ev) {...}
```

For other containers or SE you will somehow extend an AbstractProcessApplication class and overwrite the method.